# send multiple file through $http angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, python-2.7

I have a javascript array of multiple files like

```
filelist=[{'name':file1name,file:file1},{'name':file2name,file:file2}]
```

I need to send this file to backend `views.py` using `$http` request.

How do i send this in angularjs?
Please modify this link [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/B13t84j5IPzINMh1F862?p=preview)

Comment: Use:  $http({
        url: 'request-url',
        method: "POST",
        data: { 'fileList' : fileList }
    })
    .then(function(response) {
            // success
    }, 
    function(response) { //Fail
    });

Comment: https://jasonturim.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/angularjs-native-multi-file-upload-with-progress/

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/B13t84j5IPzINMh1F862?p=preview

Comment: can u please modify this?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Do you want to use more than on post operation? What form does the backend take for file uploads? Base64 or binary? **Describe** the approach you are using and the problems with that approach.